# Angularjs if else condition using json array

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am using Angularjs and I am populating data from json file. I am using ng-repeat to display data. There is a Categories, subcategories and Products. Some Categories had subcategories some categories had some products. I am trying to write condition like if categories had subcategories display subcategories and if has product then display products.

```
[{
    "category":"Cables",
    "subCategories":[
        {
            "subCategory":"Sub Category 1"

        },
        {
            "subCategory":"Sub Category 2"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "category":"Wallplates & Boxes",
    "subCategories":[
        {
            "subCategory":"Sub Category 6"
        },
        {
            "subCategory":"Sub Category 7"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "category":"Media Distribution",
    "products":[
        {
            "proTitle":"Product 1"
        },
        {
            "proTitle":"Product 2"
        }
    ]
}]
```

The controller is below.

```
var app = angular.module('analytics', []);
app.controller ('categoryCtrl', function ($scope, $http){
$http.get('json/category_data_new.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.chartValues = data;
});
```

});

I am using below code to display Categories and under subcategories

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li ng-repeat="chartValue in chartValues">
        <span ng-click="loadRecord(chartValue, $index)">
           {{chartValue.category}}
        </span>
        <ul ng-show="chartValue.subCatList">
            <li ng-repeat="item in chartValues[$index].subCategories">
                  <span ng-click="loadSubRecord(item, $index)">
                      {{item.subCategory}}
                   </span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

if any one have any idea how do this? please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Check this link here](http://jsfiddle.net/s3uf4/1/)

Two templates have been created for sub-menus

```
  <ul ng-show="chartValue.subCategories">
        <li ng-repeat="item in chartValues[$index].subCategories">
              <span ng-click="loadSubRecord(item, $index)">
                  {{item.subCategory}}
               </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
     <ul ng-show="chartValue.products">
        <li ng-repeat="item in chartValues[$index].products">
              <span ng-click="loadSubRecord(item, $index)">
                  {{item.proTitle}}
               </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
```